# A git subdirectory in an svn repository?

Tags: svn, git

I've got an existing project running in an SVN repository.  I want to make use of a 3rd-party app that's hosted on github.  All of my external apps I'm currently using are hosted in external SVN repositories, so I have a directory 'externals', that has

```
$ svn pg svn:externals externals
externalApp1     http://externalApp1.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
externalApp2     http://externalApp2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

Now, I want to add 'externalApp3' that's hosted on github and have a resulting dir structure like:

```
externals
 |- externalApp1 # svn
 |- externalApp2 # svn
  \ externalApp3 # git
```

Now, the kicker:  I want to be able to just run 'svn-update' from the root of my repository and it to automagically do a 'git pull' on my externalApp3.  Is this possible?  Are there any tools out there that would allow this?

Comment: Just BTW, you could switch it because Git has a SVN repository in its core. People could connect to the Git Repo like its SVN.

Comment: With @Chacha102's point: you could `git svn clone` your original SVN repository: you now have an SVN-commitable git repo, and you can put a git repo under it (as a submodule).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tools which support combined Git/SVN repositories, but you could try just using a script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# Name "update", call as ./update from the repository root
svn update
(cd externalApp3 && git pull)
```